# angular creating a new instance of CacheService

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using CacheService with my search screen that contains many dropdown values. It works only if you set the cache for one dropdown , it won't work if you set cache for more than one , even if they have different keys. I think I need to create a new instance of the cache service

example:

```
constructor(private _appParams: AppParamasService,private _cacheService: CacheService) {
}

getUserLocations(ID: string, allList: string) {
        let userLocationsCache: string;

        let res: any | null = this._cacheService.get(userLocationsCache);
        if (res) {
            this.results = res;

        }
        else {

            this._appParams.getUserLocations(ID, allList)
                .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.results = data.result;
                    this._cacheService.set(userLocationsCache, data.result);    

                },
                error => this.showMessage(' Method: ' + <any>error, 0));


        }
}

    getAllStatuses() {
        let statusCache: string="";

        let res1: any | null = this._cacheService.get(statusCache);
        if (res1) {
            this.iStatuses = res1;
                  }
        else {

            this._appParams.getStatuses()
                .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.iStatuses = data.result;
                    this._cacheService.set(statusCache, data.result);    
                },
                error => this.showMessage(' Method: ' + <any>error, 0));

        }
}
```

**error**

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

*************************************************UPDATE******************************************************
I took out CacheService  from application module and added the declaration at the component level..still it did not work

```
import { CacheService } from 'ng2-cache-service';
@Component({
    selector: 'search',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'search.component.html',
    providers: [CacheService]

})




export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private _appParams: AppParamasService,private _cacheService: CacheService) {
}

getUserLocations(PNSLUID: string, allList: string) {
        let userLocationsCache: string;

        let res: any | null = this._cacheService.get(userLocationsCache);
        if (res) {
            this.results = res;

        }
        else {

            this._appParams.getUserLocations(ID, allList)
                .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.results = data.result;
                    this._cacheService.set(userLocationsCache, data.result);    

                },
                error => this.showMessage(' Method: ' + <any>error, 0));


        }
}

    getAllStatuses() {
        let statusCache: string="";

        let res1: any | null = this._cacheService.get(statusCache);
        if (res1) {
            this.iStatuses = res1;
                  }
        else {

            this._appParams.getStatuses()
                .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.iStatuses = data.result;
                    this._cacheService.set(statusCache, data.result);    
                },
                error => this.showMessage(' Method: ' + <any>error, 0));

        }
}
```

**ts service**

```
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';

@Injectable()

export class AppParamasService {

    constructor(private _http: Http) {

    }

 getStatuses() {
         return this._http.get(environment.BASE_API_URL + 'GetAllStatuses/')
             .map((response: Response) => response.json())
             .catch(this.handleError);

     }
 getUserLocations(a: string, allList: string) {
         return this._http.get(environment.BASE_API_URL + 'GetUserLocations/' + a + '/' + allList)
             .map((response: Response) => response.json())
             .do(data => console.log('loctions ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
             .catch(this.handleError);
     }
```

Comment: had you exposed  CacheService as a provider in app.module.ts

Comment: yes and I took it out..see my updated above code...note it works if I do it only for one dropdown

Comment: could you post the code for the cacheservice please

Comment: added the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just inject your service (or any [@Injectable](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable)) in the constructor, Angular will walk up the component / module tree and look for providers for your service. It is highly likely that you added your service to the providers array of a module. This will result in a singleton service which is used everywhere you inject this service inside this module.

If you do want to use an independent instance of your service for your component, you can add the service to the providers array of your component, like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './my-comppnent.component.css' ],
  providers: [CacheService]
})
export class MyComponent {
...
```

Comment: still it did not work..same error..updated my code above

Comment: I don't know the exact structure of your component but I think your dropdown elements need to be independent components which each get their own instance of the CacheService (via component providers)

Comment: bu in your example dropdown is a separate a component instead having the dropdown along with all other controls in one component..not sure how will this fit my project

Comment: I do think that this is the way to go if you want to get a separate instance of your service for each of your dropdowns

Comment: yes, but this is going to complicate the project, there must be easier way..or is there another service that I can use?

Comment: one way to do it is to inject multiple instances in the constructor , thn each dropdown use one instance like this  constructor(private _appParams: AppParamasService,private _cacheService: CacheService, private _cacheService2: CacheService)

Comment: but I am not sure if this way is efficient "performance aspect "

Comment: I actually think breaking down views into small reusable components is a good thing and makes the application less complicated, but that's more of an opinion. Injecting multiple instances of your service should work too, why do you expect performance problems here?

Comment: I don't expect performance problem , but wanted to double check in case I am missing something